# ¿Cómo saber si un Array tiene el mismo valor en todos los datos?

Tags: php, array

Cómo podría saber si mi array :

```
$exampleArr4 = array("AÑO 2017","2017_01".$dieciciete01,"2017_02".$dieciciete02,
                 "2017_03".$dieciciete03,"2017_04".$dieciciete04,"2017_05".$dieciciete05  ,
                 "2017_06".$dieciciete06,"2017_07".$dieciciete07,"2017_08".$dieciciete08,
                 "2017_09".$dieciciete09,"2017_10".$dieciciete10);
```

Contiene los mismos datos y devolverme un `true` almacenado en una variable, y caso contrario si no todos son iguales devolver `false` y estos dos últimos valores (true o false), que estén almacenados en una variable.

Lo que pasa es que de acuerdo a esa variable que contenga ese valor lo quiero comparar para poder realizar un `if`

¿Alguien tiene la idea de algún método o que podría hacer?

Comment: Creo que por el formato del primer elemento del `array` es imposible que sean iguales con el resto de elementos. por lo tanto será `false` siempre. O quizá no está muy clara su pregunta y no logro entender bien lo que desea realizar.

Comment: ok, entonces si quito los primeros elementos y agrego 0=>$variable .. etc . entonces si se podría hacer lo que estoy pidiendo? comos seria método?

Comment: ¿qué es lo que pretendes hacer exactamente con esa variable y la condición de la que habals?

Comment: Aún así, sigo sin comprender el resultado esperado. el inicio de los elementos del `array` son diferentes *(2017_03, 2017_06)* desde ahí sin hacer ninguna comparación ni método sería `false`.

Comment: @Dev.Joel bueno entonces como mencione anteriormente si quito todo eso de (2017_03, 2017_06)  y lo reemplazo por  0=>$variable .. etc dentro del array si se podria comparar los valores ?

Comment: @Lixus bueno una vez que se comparen todos los valores y me devuelta almacenado en una variable no se true si todos los valores osn iguales en mi if comprararla con otra variable con el mismo valor por true para que si son iguales se oculte una grafica y si los datos no conciden en todos los valores un false y que se muestre la grafica no se si me explico

Comment: Más bien creo que la verdadera pregunta seria ¿Cómo vas a llenar ese arreglo? ¿Realmente cabe la posibilidad de todos sus elementos sean iguales ?¿

Comment: @M.Gress bueno es que las variables que están dentro del array ya tienen un valor posteriormente consultado con una sentencia SQL,solo las estoy alacenando por que después ese mismo array lo ocupo para poder mostrarlo en la grafica, pero lo que quiero es que en la consulta hay ocasiones que las variables las 9 tienen un guion como dato y en otras puede que de esas 9 solo 4 tenga un guion y los demás datos otra palabra,por eso que quiero recorrer los valores de todo el array y si todos tienen el mismo valor me devuelva un true y viceversa si son diferentes los valores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para saber si todos los elementos de un `array` son iguales. podría emplear en primer lugar la función [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php) para eliminar los valores duplicados del `array` y luego obtener la cantidad con [count()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) , si esto es igual a `1` entonces todos son iguales , caso contrario no lo serán.

```
$valores = array('0' => 'valor' , '1'=> 'valor');
$esigual = count(array_unique($valores))===1;
var_dump($esigual);
```

Sí utilizará esa porción de código varias veces sería mejor tener una función

```
function valoresIguales($array){
  return count(array_unique($array))===1;
}
var_dump(valoresIguales($valores));
```

Comment: ok creo que esto me ayuda en gran parte, entonces bueno no se mucho de esto pero entonces a la variable $esigual tendria por defecto el valor '1' asignado?

Comment: @Fernando la variable tendrá un valor `booleano`. dependiendo si son iguales o no. ya luego puede hacer algo como `if($esigual){echo "son iguales"; } else { echo "no son iguales";} `

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias! si si ya comprobé y si me vuelve los valores que necesito muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: lo lamento,  pero ya esta! de verdad gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Esta función te puede servir:

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/GXZWTS88347)

```
<?php 

$arrIgual    = array("foo", "foo", "foo", "foo");
$arrDesIgual = array("foo", "foo", "foo", "bar");

var_dump(isHomogenous($arrIgual));

var_dump(isHomogenous($arrDesIgual));


function isHomogenous($arr) {
    $firstValue = current($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        if ($firstValue !== $val) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

?>
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

---

Fuente: [Check if all values in array are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10560669/5587982)

Comment: HEY GRACIAS, también me sirvió muchas gracias ! saludos